# Cannot SSH to cloud server using terminal but can do so using Putty

Tags: ssh

I need help on SSH. I cannot SSH to the Ubuntu cloud server using Lubuntu terminal. I don't know where is the source of the problem. However, I am able to SSH to the server using Putty. Below is the terminal output. Thank you.

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 193.122.150.39 [193.122.150.39] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/luins/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 193.122.150.39:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/7QT8lVebQzkPSVPV8kAMtDDjLc4tei3UifHtvrAZi4
debug1: Host '193.122.150.39' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/luins/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: nslui@nslui-pc RSA SHA256:/4EEJJFVZ7XGXuJEyGq3hx6k3WOtpBTb4DUr8TA030E agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luins/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luins/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luins/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luins/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/luins/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: nslui@nslui-pc RSA SHA256:/4EEJJFVZ7XGXuJEyGq3hx6k3WOtpBTb4DUr8TA030E agent
debug1: Server accepts key: nslui@nslui-pc RSA SHA256:/4EEJJFVZ7XGXuJEyGq3hx6k3WOtpBTb4DUr8TA030E agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 193.122.150.39 ([193.122.150.39]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = ms_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = ms_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = ms_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = ms_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = ms_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_MY.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: i /home/luins/.ssh/ocp_key
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
bash: i: command not found
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 3660, received 3168 bytes, in 1.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 3770.1, received 3263.3
debug1: Exit status 127
```

My ssh config

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
#   GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

My ssh terminal command

```
ssh ubuntu@193.122.150.39 -i ~/.ssh/ocp_key
```

Comment: So what setting does putty have the other program does not?

Comment: Looks like you are logging in successfully (`Authentication succeeded (publickey)`) but then there are the following lines in your log: `Sending command: i /home/luins/.ssh/ocp_key` and `bash: i: command not found`. That seems to be a cause of the problem. What configuration setting makes ssh send the "i" command ? Please post your ssh config and the full command you used to login to server.

Comment: For putty, in session window, hostname 193.122.150.39 port 22, in SSH, Auth window, I insert the private key. When I click open button, the terminal will open and I enter ubuntu as login user and the session connect with no issue.

Comment: The *most likely* explanation is that you mistyped the command, putting `i` in place of `-i`. That would explain both the error message from bash, and the fact that the connection apparently authenticates using a key provided by your SSH agent rather than the one mentioned on the command line

Comment: I uninstall the openssh client and reinstall back the client service. After that I am able to login using the terminal. Thank you for all your advises.